# About random numbers in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, random, while-loop, numbers

I am really new to C++. I am following a free online course, and one thing I had to do was to create a program which could scramble the characters of a string.

So, I created a function who received the word as parameter and returned  the scrambled word. ctime and cstdlib were included and srand(time(0)); declared in the main.

Basically, the function looked like this :

```
std::string mixingWord(std::string baseWord)
{
std::string mixWord;
int pos(0);

for (int i = baseWord.length; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if (i != 0)
  {
    pos = rand() % i;
    mixWord += baseWord[pos];
    baseWord.erase(pos,1);
  }
  else
  {
    mixWord += baseWord[0];
  }
}

return mixWord;
}
```

And it worked just fine. But the correct solution was

```
std::string mixingWord(std::string baseWord)
{
std::string mixWord;
int pos(0);

while (baseWord.size() != 0)
{
    pos = rand() % baseWord.size();
    mixWord += baseWord[pos];
    baseWord.erase(pos, 1);
}

return mixWord;
}
```

And it works fine as well.
My question is :
Why is the solution working ?
From what I understood, this :

```
rand() % value
```

gives out a value between 0 and the value given.

SO, since baseWord.size() returns, let's say 5 in the event of a word like HELLO. rand will generate a number between 0 and 5. So it COULD be 5. and baseWord[5] is out of bound, so it should crash once in a while, but I tried it over 9000 times (sorry, dbz reference), and it never crashed.

Am I just unlucky, or am I not understanding something ?

Comment: Be aware of the standard library capabilities also: `std::random_shuffle(begin(baseWord), end(baseWord));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x % y` gives the remainder of `x / y`. The result can never be `y`, because if it was, then that would mean `y` could go into `x` one more time, and the remainder would actually be zero, because `y` divides `x` evenly. So to answer your question:

> Am I just unlucky, or am I not understanding something ?

You're misunderstanding something. `rand() % value` gives a result in the range `[0,value - 1]` (assuming value is positive), not `[0, value]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get it now. Actually I thought the % sign was more of an indicator than the real modulo operator, as in random between this and (%) that. That makes way more sense.

Answer (score 3):

rand() % 100 returns number between 0 and 99. This is 100 NUMBERs but includes 0 and does not include 100.

A good way to think about this is a random number (1000) % 100 = 0. If I mod a random number with the number N then there is no way to get the number N back.

Along those lines 
pos = rand() % baseWord.size();
will never return pos = baseWord.size() so in your case there will not be an indexing issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I understand how the line works now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just misunderstood the modulo operator. a % b, with a and b any integer, will return values between **0 and b-1 (inclusive)**.

As for your HELLO example, it will only return values between 0 and 4, therefore will never encounter out of bound error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as I said in another comment, I thought the % sign was more of an indicator than the real modulo operator, as in random between this and (%) that. Thanks to all of you for pointing that out.